# I have an old Lenovo laptop and WIndows 8 is giving me faulty disk errors. Every few hours I will be sent to an error and it will shut off. (ctnd down

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

The disk is always giving me faulty errors, and the battery is weak. Plus, when I go to 'Disks' on an Ubuntu USB, it will give me this:
[shows DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON and the temp is around 30C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/536T4.png)

Also, I have the SMART error for this: `5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   036    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 16392`

This is the only SMART error I have though.

Anyways, what does this mean? Is my disk going to die? If it is, its not a big problem, but would installing Ubuntu over it and wiping Windows 8 be a solution?

Please give me an answer ASAP, I would be very grateful if someone answers in the next few hours, and have a good day/night people!

Answer (score 6):

This is a hardware issue, the disk is dying. Installing an other OS over Widows8 wont help. Replace the disk, or maybe better, get a new(er) computer.

And take backups of your important data.